# Qual o melhor banco de dados para guardar uma lista de informações

Tags: php, mysql, time, armazenamento

Estou a pensar em desenvolver um projecto, neste caso um site. Vou precisar de ter uma ligação base de dados, optarei por o `mysql`. No site as pessoas poderam criar uma conta, e posteriormente criar uma lista de informação sobre elas.

**Exemplo da lista:**

```
tenho isto
fiz aquilo
estudei alem
nasci aqui
...
```

**Exemplo da Base de Dados:**

```
Tabela User
uid
uemail
upass
unome
....
```

Tabela Information

```
iid
iuid
iinfor
....
```

A minha questão é a seguinte qual é a melhor forma de guardar a lista de informação pensei em uma tabela, mas penso que futuramente pode correr mal. Quando a tabela `Information` começar a ter muitos dados posso perder muito tempo nas consultas. Existe alguma outra forma de fazer o que pretendo, sem ter essa perda de tempo ou ela não se refletira? Ou esta forma que eu penso será sempre a melhor?

Deixo ainda uma outra questão e vou pegar o exemplo do `facebook` como é armazenada toda a informação dos utilizadores, penso eu que devem ter também tudo armazenado em uma base de dados, mas apenas em uma máquina com uma quantidade anormal de processamento, certo?

Comment: Só criar outra tabela e não pode guardar de temporário pode estourar o espaço do banco de dados tem limite, recomendo nova tabela `TabelaUser_temp` blablabla e depois fazer procedure use merge é simples.

Comment: @KingRider, desculpe mas poderia explicar-se melhor

Comment: #Tmc, falando sobre cache ou buffer pool, não tem como explicar muito longo, é intermediário mySQL trabalho innodb e myisam são diferente para criar temporario (guardar), tb é diferente desempenho. Se for **cloud** que pode trabalhar **Oracle** é melhor desempenho mais rápido e não tem limite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questão é: *Qual banco de dados irei utilizar, quão estruturado está meu banco de dados e como agirá a aplicação ?*

*Um dos principais fatores que impactam no desempenho de uma instrução SQL é o uso de índices, principalmente em instruções que empregam tabelas com muitos dados. Este é um fator tão importante, que a mera criação de um índice pode reduzir drasticamente a quantidade de passos internos na execução de instruções SQL.* - fonte: [Mauro Pichiliani](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/22264/banco-de-dados/10-tecnicas-para-otimizacao-de-instrucoes-sql?trace=1519021197&source=single)

Acontece que esse método que você citou, é bastante utilizado, eu particularmente o utilizo e nunca deu bronca, olha que foram milhares de conteúdos.

## Banco de dados

O banco de dados que você vai utilizar, vai ser uma das maiores influências em relação a agilidade da pesquisa, assim como escolher o tipo de cada coluna.

Por exemplo. A aplicação pode ser estável com algumas centenas de dados usando MySQL. PostgreSQL pode ser melhor, mas nesse caso pode ser que seu uso não seja necessário.

Outro exemplo é: A lista terá alguma quantidade máxima de caracteres ? Você deve imaginar qual tipo você deve usar: Text, TinyText, MediumText, LongText e etc.

## Aplicação

Outro fator que pode impedir um bom funcionamento é como está sua aplicação;

Por exemplo: imagina que você precisa utilizar apenas o nome de quem puxou a lista, o lógico seria utilizar algo como `SELECT nome FROM tbl_lista;`, caso você utilize `SELECT * FROM tbl_lista;` a aplicação já perderá em quesito performance, entende ?

Veja essa imagem e reflita.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Não há segredo.** Então resumindo, do modo que você quer fazer não tem bronca, vai depender de como você vai aplicar.

Comment: esta então aconselhando eu a fazer sem medo achando que o mysql consiga dar conta do recado, tendo apenas em atenção alguns promenores? @MauroAlexandre

Comment: Sim. É uma saída bem bolada. No máximo é fazer o que o amigo citou: crie uma tabela temporária e depois repasse os dados para original. Eu fazia assim também. Depois de X dados , dependendo do timestamp - média ; as próximas listas eu chamava da tabela temporária,  depois de X tempo, eu traria de X em X listas da temp para original.